# enviar parámetros de un formulario para otro

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, formularios

Tengo un inicio de sesión el cual yo ingreso mi número de chasis de un automóvil.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al momento de ingresar aparece un nuevo formulario el cual contiene toda la información de ese automóvil, lo que deseo es rellenar todos los TextBox con la información de ese automóvil dependiendo del numero de chasis.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Postdata:
Estoy trabajando en 4 capas en C# y una base de datos en SQLServer en la que los datos del automóvil son: Id del automóvil, Número de chasis, Año, color, marca, modelo y antecedentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es añadir un contructor a tu form de Detalles con un parámetro código:

```
public partial class Detalles : Form
{
    public Detalles()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Detalles(string idCoche)
    {

    }

    private void Detalles_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Con esto puedes llamar desde tu pantalla principal a este formulario con tu id al clickar el botón de buscar:

```
     private void Buscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Detalles detalle = new Detalles("tucodigo");
            detalle.Show();
        }
```

Finalmente puedes manejar la búsqueda en tu base de datos desde el propio evento de carga de la página detalles, si tienes capas que accedan a la base de datos y te devuelvan los datos, como ejemplo y suponiendo que se hiciera una llamada sin procedimientos almacenados, ni clases intermedias (como ejemplo, esta práctica no está recomendada):

```
public Detalles(string idCoche)
    {
        string strSQL = "Select * From [Coches] where CocheId= @cocheId";
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("tu connection string aqui"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn))
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cocheId", idCoche);
                using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        /*
                        Manejar los datos..
                       */
                        this.TextBoxChasis = reader["numeroChasis"].toSring();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT para adaptarlo a las 3 capas:
La capa de presentación es la que ya te he explicado, es decir lo que está viendo el usuario. La capa de negocio, simplificándolo podría ser una sola clase llamada Coche.cs con los atributos que quieras. EJ:

```
public class Coche
{
    public string cocheId { get; set; }
    public int numeroChasis { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public string marca { get; set; }
}
```

Y podemos crear un constructor que reciba el ID:

```
 public Coche(string id)
 {

 }
```

Y aquí podemos llamar  la capa de datos, que será una nueva clase que devolverá un Coche desde base de datos: GetCoche.cs

Dentro de nuestra nueva clase GetCoche.cs crearemos una clase que accederá a la BBDD

```
public static class GetCoche
{
    public static Coche GetCocheById(string id)
    {
        Coche locCoche = new Coche();
        string strSQL = "Select * From [Coches] where CocheId= @cocheId";
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("tu connection string aqui"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn))
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cocheId", id);
                using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        /*Lo que haya dentro de los [CORCHETES] debe coincidir con el nombre de la columna de tu base de datos*/
                        locCoche.numeroChasis= reader["numeroChasis"].toSring();
                        locCoche.year = reader["year"].toSring();
        /*Rellenar con todos tus datos..*/
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return locCoche;
    }
}
```

Por tanto en la capa anterior rellenearemos el último método que habíamos creado :

```
    public Coche(string id)
    {
        Coche  locCoche= GetCoche.GetCocheById(id);
        this.cocheId = locCoche.cocheId;
        this.marca = locCoche.marca;
        /*Rellenar todo...*/
    }
```

Por último en la capa de presentación, en el momento de iniciar el winform con un string llamaremos a nuestra nueva clase:

```
    public Detalles(string idCoche)
    {
        Coche locCoche = new Coche(idCoche);
        this.TextBoxChasis = locCoche.numeroChasis;
        /*Rellenar con todos tus datos..*/
    }
```

Nota: Lo he hecho para que te hagas una idea del esquema, no es la manera más correcta de hacerlo, lo ideal es que te crees únicamente la clase Coche con sus correspondientes Request(id) y Response(el propio coche), la clase que reciba estos request y llame a la capa de datos que rellene el response, y la clase de la capa de datos en sí.

Comment: Podrias explicarme por favor como seria con la capa de datos,negocio y la capa de presentacion . No pude realizarlo

Comment: Te lo añado como edit